# How to work with Google Map API for a non-English address?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

One of the core business domain objects of our application has an address attribute. So far, it works correctly for an English address in North American. For a non-English speaking country, an address search can be done with both the native language and English with the Google Map API as long as the native language is supported by Google Map API. I am wondering how to make our core business domain object work with a such dual language address search. One approach is to have different language version of address. This approach, however, isn't practical because we can't ask user to enter their address in two languages. Another approach I can think of is to convert an address in one language to a pair of latitude and longitude through Google Map API and conduct the search with the latitude and longitude data. A question with this approach is how to deal with location name such as a city instead of a precise address. I am wondering whether others have used this approach or not. If so, do you mind of sharing your experience?

Comment: When you load the map are you able to specify the language parameter specific to the language of your address?

Comment: This should help you out https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Language

Comment: @Verma Thanks for the reference link. I actually already read the section of Google Map document. My question is that how to make an address search work for various languages with a help from Google Map API when our application only has an address data in one language.